# JQuery iterate through string occurrences

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, offset

I've an HTML like this

blalblala < span id="myID" >bla < /span> blalba < span id="myID > bla< /span> and so on...

Now I would to get the left position of all items of kind myID.
I've tried with this code

```
var x = "";   
$('.myID').each(function(index) { 
    x += " " + $(this).position().left+",";  
}); 
return x;
```

But it's wrong because it does not return anything.
What's wrong?
Thanks

Comment: [Works for me](http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/Utr9E/) (Assuming you change your ID's to Classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x = new Array;
$('.myID').each(function(index) { x[index] = $(this).position().left; });
console.log(x);
```

try that and see what is present in the array x.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use id on more than one element.  The appropriate attribute to use is class.

```
<span class="myClass" >bla < /span> 
<span class="myClass"> bla< /span>
```

And then your code should work if you update the selector to be:

```
$('.myClass')
```

Answer (score 0):

- you have multiple identical IDs in your document [fragment]
- you are using the class selector, while you have IDs

To quote the freenode#css bot:

> Explore the intricacies of HTML and CSS here: http://wsc.opera.com/ , http://www.htmlhelp.com/ , http://css-discuss.incutio.com/ , http://www.brainjar.com/ , http://www.htmldog.com/ , http://css.maxdesign.com.au/